# Postgresql Distinct on Order By

Tags: postgresql

I have data that looks like the table below.

```
   date       value symbol  time        id
0 2014-01-01      0      A 2014-01-01   65
1 2014-01-02      1      B 2014-01-02   66
2 2014-01-03      2      A 2014-01-03   65
3 2014-01-04      3      B 2014-01-04   66
4 2014-01-05      5      A 2014-01-05   65
5 2014-01-05      4      A 2014-01-05   65
6 2014-01-06      6      B 2014-01-06   66
```

I'm trying to write an expression that will do a sort on `symbol` and `value`, and then a distinct on `date` and `id`. From what I understand, this isn't possible, since the distinct on needs to match what I order by.

What I want is to get the above table, but without row 4, since it will sort on `symbol` and `value` ascending, and then distinct and choose the first row in that sorted table. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DISTINCT ON` eliminates duplicates by selecting the *first* row as defined by the rest of the fields present in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("date", "id") 
       "pk", "date", "value", "symbol", "time", "id"
FROM mytable
ORDER BY "date", "id", "value", "symbol"
```

The above query will choose for every `"date", "id"` slice the *first* row as defined by order of `"value", "symbol"` within that slice, hence it will exclude row with `"pk" = 4`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/35250/2)